# Explain class, method, function?

Tags: oop

I am not clear what these terms mean:

- Class
- Method
- Function

Can you please explain these terms to me?

Comment: google: `java class method funcion `

Comment: What materials do you use for studying if they do not provide this information in chapter 1?

Comment: Java doesn't have fuction, funcion or functions, it only has methods. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should first begin with Object Oriented development (maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Because the class, method and function topics are not Java-specific.

Then you can see how Java works and how to build classes with it.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a way of representing a group of objects.  Sun/Oracle describes more about a class in [What is a class?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)  For example a car is a class of motorized vehicles with four wheels (among other things)

A method is a section of code that is [declared](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) to take some arguments (things like numbers) and return a value of a given type.  A method has a body that determines what it does.  Other parts of your code can [call](http://java.sun.com/new2java/divelog/part1/page6.jsp) that method, at which point the code in your method is run and the return value can be used by the code doing the calling.

The word function is not really used when discussing Java, but if it is used it is a synonym for method.

Comment: Classes aren't often defined in terms of what they lack; your `Car` class, for example, probably wouldn't contain any mention of truck beds, unless for some odd reason it extended `Truck` and you wanted to specifically remove support for capabilities of a truck.  That's generally bad design, though.

Comment: That specific process of calling methods is very ... specific and not required by the JVM spec. It's also not really relevant to the understanding of the concept of a method. Specifically storing the "return adress" is not part of Java.

Comment: @Joachim - since the OP didn't seem to know what a method was at alll, I was explaining the general process, but have removed it.